bin data after filtering
I have an experimental dataset in which I could see a feature when plotting a 2D histogram:

As it can be noticed, there is something appearing in the region around 218.46 in the x-axis and 86000 in the y-axis.
After filtering and aggregation my dataset with this
edc = (
    df_TR.filter(
        (pl.col("t") > 85_700)
        & (pl.col("t") < 86_090)
        & (pl.col("delay") > 218.30)
        & (pl.col("delay") < 218.72)
    )
    .group_by("delay").agg(pl.col("t").sum().alias("sum_t")
)

The resulting plot I'm getting is this one:
f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(edc["delay"], edc["sum_t"], ".")
ax.set_ylim(0, 1e7);


But that's not exactly what I have in mind because I would need to bin the data after filtering/grouping in order to produce something like this (forget about the fitting, as this plot belongs to another experiment):

But I can't find a "binning" operation in polars.
I would need to bin the delay axis and in each of those bins, sum (or average) all the times.
Any ideas how to achieve that?

Without knowing the origin of the data and what you should see, I consider is the problem, in my opinion the region you have filter is just the same as the rest and is why you don't see the expected result. In other words I do not see a clear signal in the first image you have plotted in the region you are filtering. In
my experience in the Lab would repeat the experiment...

Are you looking for hist
